# Change text field value dynamically according to a non related entity

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I have a CKEditor input field to type messages (using the IvoryCKEditor Bundle), stored in an entity called Event.

I also have an entity called Reply, which stores messages archetypes.

So, the viewer can write messages directly, or select a message archetype thanks to a dropdown list. [View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VP7y.png)

Reply entities have two atributes : name and text. 
The name is displayed in the dropdown list, and when selected, **I would like the text to be set in the text field.**

I saw this : [dynamic generation of submitted form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms), but it only works if the field that my text field depends on is on the form, which is not the case.

I wonder if I can do that with Jquery.

I would have to access the text attribute of the Reply entity selected, and put it in the textarea field.

At the moment I tried this, to see if I can change the value of my textarea.

```
$("#reply").change(function(){

    $('#message').var("Bonjour");

});
```

with

```
<select id="reply" class="form-control">
    <option>
        {{"tracker.reply.labels.none" | trans | capitalize }}
    </option>
    {% for reply in replies %}
        <option>
            {{reply.name}}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and

```
<span id="message" class="col-md-10">
    {{form_errors(formadd.text)}}
    {{form_widget(formadd.text)}}
</span>
```

which doesnt work : $('#message').var("bonjour"); doesnt do anything. (No errors though).

I tried replacing $("#message") by $(".cke-editable") as the span id="message" contains a LOT of nested tags, thanks to CKEditor Wysywig, with eventually these lines :

```
<body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">

   <p>{#text displayed in the field#}</p>

</body>
```

Of course, any help would be appreciated, regarding

- how to proceed in general,
- how to access the attributes of the Reply in the JQuery code,
- and how to change the textarea value.

Feel free to ask for more code.

Thank you.

Comment: From your description I think you maybe over complicating things.  If your form needs a particular piece of data to do it's job then give it that data.

Comment: I believe what I'm trying to do can't be achieved this way, as I would need to add some relations between my two Entities, which I can't do.

Comment: Sure seems like all you are trying to do is to transfer a bit of data from one entity to another.  Form events will give you the necessary hooks.  No need for relations.  But jquery is fine as well.  Probably a better user experience anyways.

Comment: if JQuery is fine, then the problem is solved !

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to replace contents of CKEditor form element according to currently selected option in select form element.

First, your select options should have values, so add them in Twig template:

```
{% for reply in replies %}
    <option value="{{ reply.name }}">
        {{ reply.name }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
```

Second, you should get your CKEditor instance:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['message']; // or replace 'message' with your ckeditor ID
```

Lastly, you can create jQuery code that will replace contents of CKEditor, you shouldn't use `.var()`, use `.setData('value')` as in [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData). You can implement a simple `switch` with values from your select options, that changes text accordingly to selected one like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reply').change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'Test1':
        editor.setData('The test text1');
        break;

      case 'Test2':
        editor.setData('The test text2');
        break;

      default:
        editor.setData('');
        break;
    }
  })
});
```

[Here is jsfiddle example of above](https://jsfiddle.net/9vpc8phf/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It does help a lot.

However, when I do the  CKEditor.replace('message') it changes the rendering of the form, I get the full toolbar version.

I deployed it using this code : 

`$builder  
            ->add('text', CKEditorType::class, array (
                'config_name' => 'my_config',
                'label' => false
                
            ))`

in the form class.

So maybe I should get the instance with something else, but I don't know what. I'll check out the documentation.

Comment: Ups, I am new in web development, didn't realize that CKEditor was such a thing, and existed outside of Symfony.

I should propably mention that I'm using the IvoryCKEditor Bundle.

Comment: @abernard Try removing `var editor = CKEditor.replace('message')`, and change it to `var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['message']` - or replace 'message' with the CKEditor ID you used in Symfony form

Comment: Ok I tried it. Got the output : "editor undefined"

I tried  replacing 'message' with formadd.text too but of course JQuery does not know about my form formadd. Maybe if I can pass form data from twig to jquery ? (wild guess)

Comment: @abernard IvoryCkeditorBundle should add the `CKEDITOR.replace('some_form_id')` in the generated content of page. Try looking for it in HTML source by web browser. When you find it, you should use that ID to add code **BELOW generated form** to get the instance `var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['some_form_id']`. If you adding that in top of your view, the CKEDITOR is not declared yet and throws undefined error